# Functional programming polymorphism

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How to use polymorphism and SOLID principles in Functional programming?

Example  - I have different classes for different type of fields. like that:

```
class Textfield {
  setDefaultValue(){ .. code}
  setValue(){...}
  ...
}
class PasswordField {
  setDefaultValue(){ return false; }
}
```

In OOP it is easy - just add another class like "SelectField" add the methods and it will work.

But in FP how to do it:
The first is is like this:

```
function setDefaultValue(field) {
   if (field.type == 'textfield')...
   else if (field.type == 'passwordfield')..
}
```

But this breaks Open-Closed principle, because if I want to add another field "SelectField" I have to change the if statements.

Is there better way to do it (the code is latest JavaScript).

Comment: This is known as the "expression problem". Note that OOP has a symmetrically related problem: if you want to add a new function you need to change the classes.

Comment: Yes but if i want to add new type i dont have to change all the functions where if statements are

Comment: @user2693928 Why do you think that in functional programming you needed those `if` statements? Just use `field` object with a `setDefaultValue` function property. Your code is made functional by keeping stuff immutable, not by avoiding objects.

Comment: Because in setDefaultValue i have to call database or file or some external side effect that's why.